# GCP Composer - Airflow timezones: Change Airflow core timezone does not take effect

Tags: datetime, timezone, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using GCP Composer(airflow).
What I want to do is to change Airflow, in all its components, to reflect my Time Zone: "Europe/Lisbon".
I know that, by default, Composer uses timedates in UTC timezone, so I alredy proceed on some steps to change that, but, without being able to change in all components.

**What I already did was:**

- 1 Change Composer properties - Airflow Configuration Overwrites - with values:

  - webserver - default_ui_timezone: "Europe/Lisbon"
  - core - default_timezone: "Europe/Lisbon"
- 2 create DAGs timezone aware  :

  - I am using pendulum library, and specifying timezone. The scheduled is working accordley with my timezone.

**What is working as expected?:**

- The Webserver UI is presented in my timezone - WebUI: OK
- The DAG being executed accordly with the cron on my timezone - Scheduling: OK

**What is the issue?**

- It seams that internally Composer is not using my timezone as Default.
  As example, looking for Task Log, the AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE is still in UTC:

```
(...)  
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00   
(...)   
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1416} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=timezone_aware_dag3, task_id=task_one, execution_date=20230414T115800, start_date=20230414T115904, end_date=20230414T115906
```

So, I have my logs messages in WEST (***12:59:06 WEST***), but internal date meatadate still in UTC (***execution_date=20230414T115800***)

Another issue is looking for the Schedule time, vs executed time, where Airflow shows Logs, accordly with UTC, but the scheduler, accordly with my local time.
See the image in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vT5C_6Q2xNLTzcRV1kgxijRigiXLypWM/view?usp=share_link

***Expected behaviour:***
Once I changed airflow core timezone, what I was expecting was that all times were handled in my timezone.

Complete Log of a Task execution:

```
[2023-04-14, 12:59:03 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1180} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: timezone_aware_dag3.task_one scheduled__2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1180} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: timezone_aware_dag3.task_one scheduled__2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1377} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1378} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 3
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1379} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1398} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): task_one> on 2023-04-14 11:58:00+00:00
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 6068 to run task
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'timezone_aware_dag3', 'task_one', 'scheduled__2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00', '--job-id', '340', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/5-dag_timezone_aware3.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpy4s2bwl1', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpessqsl6w']
[2023-04-14, 12:59:04 WEST] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 340: Subtask task_one
[2023-04-14, 12:59:05 WEST] {task_command.py:375} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: timezone_aware_dag3.task_one scheduled__2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-ch98z
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1591} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=vsilva
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=timezone_aware_dag3
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=task_one
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2023-04-14T11:58:00+00:00
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Function One
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - DAG Timezone:
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Timezone('Europe/Lisbon')
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {python.py:173} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {taskinstance.py:1416} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=timezone_aware_dag3, task_id=task_one, execution_date=20230414T115800, start_date=20230414T115904, end_date=20230414T115906
[2023-04-14, 12:59:06 WEST] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-04-14, 12:59:07 WEST] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```